# Excel shared file randomly locking specific cells

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a shared file with 6 cells that are unprotected (D2:F3), with all other cells being locked under sheet protections. We have employees entering into these cells once a day, but occasionally we will get an issue where cells D2 and D3 will lock on their own. I tried recreating the file, but that did not work.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and if so, how can I fix it?